# HTML+CSS Text in a Box

Tags: html, css, alignment, center, box

I faced a problem with css and html. I need to center the text in the box. When I place text, all boxes are going bottom little bit.
Here is my code

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #cce;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="3box">
    <div class="box">
        <p>Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `vertical-align: top;` and `text-align: center;` to `.box` like this:

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #cce;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="3box">
    <div class="box">
        <p>Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To center the text vertical and horizontal and dont wanna care about the text length you can do it with the table - table-cell method like

```css
.box {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: #cce;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10px;
        display: table;
    }

.box p {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

```html
 <div id="3box">
        <div class="box">
            <p>Title</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
    </div>
```

This provides also a great browser support.

Answer (score 0):

To center text in the blocks add `text-align: center;`

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: #cce;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="3box">
    <div class="box">
        <p>Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
</div>
```